# Create a custom drop down list for selecting where to move a folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I need to make a dropdown list that contains all the possible directories a folder can be moved to.

The structure of the dropdown list must be as follows:

```
Main directory
    Sub directory
       Sub Sub directory
          ect directory
Main directory
    Sub directory
       Sub Sub directory
          ect directory
Main directory
    Sub directory
```

The amount of directories and sub directories can not be hard coded because it is subject to change.
Each directory in the dropdown list must be a selectable value

This is my current code that puts the whole file path into the dropdown list

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(pathToFollowForMove, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
ddlFolders.Items.Clear();

foreach (string dir in dirs)
{
    int dirLength = dir.IndexOf(@"\U\");
    string listItem = dir.Substring(dirLength);

    if (!listItem.Contains(@"\bin"))
    {
        ddlFolders.Items.Insert(0, listItem);
    }
}
```

How I get the selected value:

```
string newDirectory = ddlFolders.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

The html code for the dropdown list:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFolders" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using a tree view. After all, your question is one to select folders, and folders are in a tree hierarchy structure.

I would suggest that using a dropdown to select some folder will not give the user any sense of a folder like structure.

And VERY interesting is that the tree view supports "on demand" loading. This means you could supply the tree view your root folder (c:) of your hard drive, and yet load time would be instant (since sub folders require the parent folder to be expanded, and such loading of sub folders only occurs on expanding a given parent folder).

In fact, such code is not even recursive, and you only need to start at some "root" folder for this to work.

So, say this simple markup:

```
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <h3>Select folders</h3>

        <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ImageSet="XPFileExplorer"
            NodeIndent="15" OnTreeNodeExpanded="TreeView1_TreeNodeExpanded"  >
            <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#6666AA" />
            <NodeStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black"
                HorizontalPadding="2px" NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
            <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
            <SelectedNodeStyle BackColor="#B5B5B5" Font-Underline="False"
                HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
        </asp:TreeView>
```

And the code behind is also rather simple:

```
    string sRoot = @"C:\Users\Kalla\source\repos";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Label1.Text = sRoot;

            DirectoryInfo[] MyFolders;
            MyFolders = GetFolders(sRoot);
            LoadTreeFiles(sRoot, MyFolders, "", null);
        }
    }

    public DirectoryInfo[] GetFolders(string sRoot)

    {
        DirectoryInfo MyDir = new DirectoryInfo(sRoot);
        DirectoryInfo[] cResultFolder; 
        cResultFolder = MyDir.GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        return cResultFolder;
    }

    public void LoadTreeFiles(string fRootL,
                            DirectoryInfo[] lParent,
                            string sParentID,
                            TreeNode tTreeNode)
    {
        // get all folders (if any)
        foreach (DirectoryInfo sFolder in lParent)
        {
            TreeNode child = new TreeNode();
            child.Text = sFolder.Name;
            child.Value = sFolder.FullName;
            child.Expanded = false;
            child.PopulateOnDemand = true;
            child.ShowCheckBox = true;

            if (sParentID == "")
                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(child);
            else
                tTreeNode.ChildNodes.Add(child);
        }
    }

    protected void TreeView1_TreeNodeExpanded(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode child = e.Node;
        DirectoryInfo[] dtChild = GetFolders(child.Value);

        LoadTreeFiles(child.Value, dtChild, child.Text, child);

    }
```

And the result is this:

[image]

Now, one could pre-fill all the folders, but as above shows, by loading on demand, then sub folders are not loaded nor traversed until you expand a given folder. This as noted means performance should be near instant, even if you started from the root of the hard drive (thus large numbers of folders and files can be supported with this approach).

It is a simple matter then to loop/show the list of selected folders after above with the TreeView.CheckedNodes collection.

And if this is for just selecting a few folders, then I would consider using a different image for the folders, say like this:

[image]

So, above is a good starting point, and in place of some dropdown which is difficult to display many folders, we see that using a simple tree view can display and allow selecting of folders with ease.

Comment: Thank for the help. The code works perfectly. Is there a way to put the treeview inside of a modal?

Comment: Well, if you use a jQuery.UI dialog, then yes, you could popup a dialog, and have the treeview inside of that dialog. However, like any/most dialogs, any post-back will in most cases collapse the dialog. So, either you dump the "on-demand" loading, and load all folders on first load. Or place the popup div (jQuery.UI dialog) inside of a update panel, and the update panel will survive  a post-back. So, this much depends on how many folders deep you plan/need to go. If a lot, then pre loading all sub folders could be some what slow, so then update panel makes sense, else pre-loading is ok

Comment: And how do I get the select nodes value in C# code

Comment: from my post quote: "It is a simple matter then to loop/show the list of selected folders after above with the TreeView.CheckedNodes collection."